# Protocol or correct syntax for adding even and odd random integers

Tags: python, list, loops

I am writing a program and I want to create a list, maybe two if needed. Ten even and odd random numbers (1, 100) with the sums of each, [even] and [odd]. I have tried to do this many ways, but want to keep it as simple as possible. Im just getting a little frustrated. I will include what I have now and maybe someone can interject something that will be useful. I have just the basics now because it is confusing to see what I had prior.

```
import random


def main():
    total_odd = 0
    total_even = 0
    num_list = []

    for count in range(10):
        num = random.randint(1, 100)
        num_list.append(num)
        total_odd += num 
        total_even += num 

    print(total_odd, total_even)
    print(num_list)



main()
```

Output =

> > > 485 485
> > >       [76, 76, 74, 2, 9, 30, 30, 29, 66, 93]

Im not looking for the answer, I will eventually figure it out, but maybe just some guidance would help out a lot.

Thank you to anyone that can help shed some light...

Comment: You meant `num_list`, didnt you?

Comment: Yes I should create two I am thinking.

Comment: You don't have to, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's just what it says: `nums` is not iterable.  `nums` is a single integer, not a list.  Perhaps you meant to iterate over `num_list` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a typo. You should be iterating over `num_list`

```
for num in num_list:
```

Also, you don't have to store the numbers in a list, you can simply do

```
total_odd, total_even = 0, 0
for count in range(10):
    num = random.randint(1, 100) % 2
    total_odd  += num
    total_even += num == 0
print(total_odd, total_even)
```

Whenever a random number is generated, if the remainder of the division by 2 is 1, then `total_odd` will be incremented by 1, otherwise `total_even` will be incremented by 1.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/numbers.py", line 26, in <module>
    main() # calls main
  File "E:/numbers.py", line 19, in main
    total_odd += num
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total_odd' referenced before assignment

Comment: >>> 
8 2
>>> This is the output I get with that, I know it should be easy and a number of ways to do this, but I guess I'm just too tired to think straight. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user3818550 Please provide the complete input you provided

Comment: import random


def main():
    total_odd = 0
    total_even = 0

    for count in range(10):
        num = random.randint(1, 100) % 2 
        total_odd += num
        total_even += num == 0
        
    print(total_odd, total_even)

    

main()